# Formatting dates using a condition

Tags: r, loops, date

I am using "R" to format a character variable that has two different kinds of date formats (MM-DD-YYYY & YYYY-MM-DD). The second is an excel origin date.

```
DateVar <- c("12-07-2017", "43229", "43137", "03-27-2018")
```

I created vector using grepl to identify both types and then a for loop to apply the as.date function to only the "excel origin dates".

```
indicator <- !grepl("-", DateVar)

for(i in indicator == TRUE){
as.date(DateVar, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

It is not working for me however, so I am looking if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things: The `for` loop is unnecessary - just subset DateVar with `[indicator]`. Second, it's `as.Date`, not `as.date` (note the "D"). Third, since it's a character vector, you need to pass the origin numbers through `as.integer` for as.Date to be able to work with them:

```
as.Date(as.integer(DateVar[indicator]), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

(or, without the intervening indicator assignment:

```
as.Date(as.integer(DateVar[!grepl("-",DateVar)]), origin = "1899-12-30")

[1] "2018-05-09" "2018-02-06"
```

If you wish to input these dates back into DateVar, you again use the subset function:

```
DateVar[indicator]<-format(as.Date(as.integer(DateVar[indicator]), origin = "1899-12-30"), "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply as I am fairly new to "R". This appears to work for my case, however my followup question would be "How can I apply to this my existing variable?". I tried to use dplyr::mutate and apply the as.Date function you provided above but I get an error message.

Comment: You want to change DateVar so that the origin dates become class Date?

Comment: Yes - or alternatively change the other date format be be YYYY-MM-DD since that is the format the excel origin dates are in. I just want to have a consistent date format for my DateVar variable.